# R convert column names that contain dates to 'Month Year' format

Tags: r

My dataset looks like this -

```
dataset = data.frame(ID=c(1:5),"2019-03-31"=runif(5,0,1),"2019-04-30"=runif(5,0,1),"2019-05-31"=runif(5,0,1),Avg=runif(5,0,1),Var=runif(5,0,1))

#Correct date names
names(dataset)[2]="2019-03-31"
names(dataset)[3]="2019-04-30"
names(dataset)[4]="2019-05-31"
```

I'm trying figure out how to convert the dates in the column names to `Month Year` format.

That is, the column name "2019-03-31" would become `March 2019`

My attempt is resulting in an empty column name

```
names(dataset)[2]=as.Date(names(dataset)[2],format="%B %Y")
```

Any guidance in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
colnames(dataset)[2:4] <- format(as.Date(colnames(dataset)[2:4]), "%b %Y")
```

Also when creating the example `dataset`, use `check.names = FALSE` to avoid adding `X` to the start of the dates.